# Angular broadcast not working with independent service

Tags: angularjs, events, service, scope, broadcast

I'm currently trying to use the $rootScope.$broadcast methods to trigger events in my angularjs services. For that purpose I've created one service responsible to trigger the events and I setup a different service to pickup the event. The important thing is that the service that picks up the event should be independent from the rest of the app which is why I went with the shared service approach.

My Broadcast Service (shared), which gets called in my app to trigger events:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('phaseListener', ['$log', '$rootScope',  function ($log, $rootScope) {

    var phaseListener= {};

    phaseListener.broadcastPhase = function(phase) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('test');
    };

    return phaseListener;
}]);
```

In the following service 'testService' I'm listening to this event but it doesn't get triggered. I'm calling the broadcastPhase() method from another service and the method gets triggered.

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('testService', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', 'phaseListener', 
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, phaseListener) {   

    $rootScope.$on('test', function() {
      $log.debug('This works');
    });

  }]);
```

If I'm listening to the event in a currently loaded Controller it works. But my goal is to trigger events in other Controllers/Services which are not currently loaded (at least not yet visible on the page). By defining the phaseListener as a dependency to testService I was hoping it does get loaded in the background.

How can I achieve this communication by defining the dependencies as I have? I can't define testService as a dependency of the phaseListener. The testService is an example of a module that can be coded separately and allows it to be easily integrated with my app.

Dependencies:
Service 1 => SharedService <= Service 2

Messaging:
Service 1 => SharedService => Service 2

Comment: As these controllers/services aren't loaded, the `$on` listener isn't loaded either. So this will never work. You'll have to make sure the service or controller functions have run is you want them to 'listen' to the events.

Comment: how do I best do that if I can't add a dependency in my phaseListener service?

Comment: Personally I would use UI-router to change the 'state' of the app once a certain event is fired. The state is could be coupled with controllers/services/templates. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I found a neat way to achieve what I was looking for. Maybe someone can use it: As I don't know all the services that will have to listen to the broadcast events at startup, I can't add the dependency as you would normally do in angular. Instead I can manually inject the service at runtime via "$injector.get('serviceName');". After this call the service is injected and any subsequent broadcast will also arrive at the newly injected service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a neat way to achieve what I was looking for. Maybe someone can use it: As I don't know all the services that will have to listen to the broadcast events at startup, I can't add the dependency as you would normally do in angular. Instead I can manually inject the service at runtime via "$injector.get('serviceName');". After this the service is injected and any subsequent broadcast will also arrive at the newly injected service.

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons, so while it's true that they have to be loaded for them to work, once they are there isn't much cost for having them instantiated. It's not like you're going to end up with 12 copies. I use this pattern every day and I've found it's best to just make all services dependencies of app.js. In my main 'run' handler I inject all of the major services I plan to use. This guarantees that they're available, and that they're loaded before anybody else starts doing anything that might emit events. It doesn't take much RAM to load them, and there's no workload until an event actually gets fired. There's very little reason not to do this - services were made to be global entities, and lazy loading them doesn't have much value.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myService1', 'myService2', 'myService3'])
.run(['$rootScope', 'myService1', 'myService2', 'myService3', function() {
    // NOTE: You may or may not actually need to do anything here. But by asking the
    // injector for each service you can guarantee that they're loaded when the app
    // starts. That lets them set up any listeners necessary for them to function.
    // Note that the order in which you ask for them here will determine the order in
    // which they're instantiated!
});
```

You might also consider using 'service' rather than 'factory'. You're not taking advantage of the difference between the two so a factory doesn't give you any benefit. A service is basically just shorthand for a factory's "you typically are going to want it THIS way..." mechanism, and you'll save two lines of code (the `var` definition, and the `return` statement) if you use a service instead:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .service('phaseListener', ['$log', '$rootScope',  function ($log, $rootScope) {
        this.broadcastPhase = function(phase) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('test');
        };
    }]);
```

You can still define scope-locals in a service if you want - but it's optional.

The only time I wouldn't do this is if there were many dozens of them... but in that case I would question the architecture of the app. I'm building an extremely complicated app with a 6-month dev cycle and we only have 9 services so far. It's just anecdotal, but I'd still be surprised to see somebody make a good case for an app with 30+ of them. Usually at that point you're wanting to reconsider what the 'manager' pattern is actually doing for you and this is where factories and providers are actually useful. There you can have the core service handling all the pub/sub work and managing smart objects within it that do the various specific functions depending on the state of the app.

A great example of something like this is a modal window manager. You might have several types of modals all with different behavior. Instead of making three services, you could make one master service that was capable of producing each type based on a parameter. Then you could differentiate between lightboxes and "pure" modals, but still manage them through a single service.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This confirms what I was afraid of. I guess I'll have to somehow wire the services in at startup. I was hoping to create some kind of module/plugin type of architecture where you can write your own service/controller and plug it into the base app without having to change anything in the existing app. It seems I'll have to introduce some dummy service to handle all dependencies. Thanks also for the hint with the factory/service - I'll definately have a look at that.